# I've to integrate various Tableau dashboard links in simple web page using html and js with only one login page

Tags: javascript, html, tableau-api

I'm trying to integrate all the Tableau dashboard links of my company in a simple web page. The problem is while opening each link,i've to enter the login credentials everytime. 
I want to create a single login page to access all the dashboards without entering credentials more than once.

Comment: how are you logging the users? have you a database? which server-side language are you using?

Comment: I've just started the project.I've initially created a login page and using hard-coded login credentials for now. After entering login credentials a tab will open which will contain list of dashboards.As soon as I open the dashboard,it is asking for login credentials again.I've to enter the login details everytime to view the dashboards. 
I will get the table which will contain the user's details. I will use either Python or Java script as server side language.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By the comments: You can't use Javascript as a server side language, since its a client-side language. Although there's the node.js, I would suggest that you go for Python, JAVA or PHP.

On Client-side, you can use cookies (with Javascript), or the HTML5 Web Storage feature to store users login information.

On Server-side, with PHP, you can use $_SESSION to store the login status of users.

I prefer the Server-side way, since it's more secure to store the login information in the server, despite the session hijacking issues.